# Making GameObject appear and disappear for a finite amount of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm trying to make a GameObject appear and disappear for a finite amount of time (Lets put the time function aside for now).

Here's what I came out with:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy1Behavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Making enemy 1 invisible
        Debug.Log("Update called");
        DisappearanceLogic(gameObject);
    }

    private static void DisappearanceLogic(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        int num = 0;
        while (num >= 0)
        {
            if (num % 2 == 0)
            {
                 gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                 gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I click the play button in `Unity` the program just don't respond, and I can only quit it from the task manager using `End Task`.

(And yes I know there a infinite loop in the method).

So I guess Im doing something wrong. What is the best way for making a `Gameobject` Blink/Flash/appear-disappear in `Unity`?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Remove the while loop and put the num variable at class level, but it will be too quick to see.

Comment: @Catwood So if num%100 = 2. I will give it a try.

Comment: good idea with 100 instead of 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an infinite loop which locks your Update() completely, because num will always be greater then 0.

So you could use InvokeRepeating (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

```
public GameObject gameobj;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("DisappearanceLogic", 0, interval);
}

void DisappearanceLogic() 
{
     if(gameobj.activeSelf) 
     {
         gameobj.SetActive(false);
     }
     else
     {
         gameobj.SetActive(true);
     }
}
```

interval is a float - something like 1f 0.5f etc.

Comment: It just sais `Trying to Invoke method: GameObject.Disappearance couldn't be called`.

Comment: Did you remove the parameter of DisapperanceLogic()? Further you have to set the `object` variable in the `Start` function for example.

Comment: But I need that parameter. this script is to make this GameObject appear and disappear and vice versa.

Comment: You don't. Add the gameobject as a property and use that. It seems like you always use the gameobject which has this code attached to it.

Comment: I should use gameObject = GetComponent<GameObject>()?in the start?

Comment: Ok I got it. I was needed to use GameObject.Find() for that. Thank you, although Its kind of round approach to do it.

Comment: It sounds like the question is blinking the gameobject the component is attached to, so you could just use [`gameObject`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html). No field needed! Although even with the field, `gameobj = gameObject` would have been enough, no need for `Find`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make animation for blinking etc - [Animations in Mecanim](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/animate-anything). Appearing and disappearing you can achieve using `gameObject.SetActive(true/false);`. If you want to make something with time its better to use [Coroutines](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/coroutines) or just Invoke with delay parameter - [Invoke Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html).

Comment: Lets leave the time for now please. But I tried using the SetActive() method in the example code in the question which didn't worked.

Comment: If `ogameObject` is disabled scripts attached to this object also will be disabled. You can e.g make a root object with script attached and add child object which will be Your main object. Or if you need to hide only GFX you can also disable `Renderer`.